# Changing all null values in sql db to set value

Tags: mysql, sql

To update some fields in my sql database, I want to change the value of multiple records for one column.

Let's say the column is named `my_column`, the value for the record of this column is currently `NULL` and I want to change it to the string `This interesting value`. The type of the column is varchar.

I used:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `my_column ` = 'This interesting value' WHERE  `my_column` =  NULL;
```

But no records are being updated this way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET `my_column ` = 'This interesting value' 
WHERE  `my_column` IS  NULL;
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Solved my issue, thank you! I can't yet accept your answer, will do it when it lets me :)

Comment: np, when you work with sql and null values a lot this becomes daily so you know it right away when you see = instead of IS with a null value

Comment: Yeah I used another query where the value was set to NULL, where the value was '0'. So that was with =, got me confused. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
      SET `my_column ` = 'This interesting value' 
 WHERE  `my_column` IS  NULL;
```